# Adding users to a list MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form in which the user is supposed to enter `Name` and `Wage` and click a button Add. When the button "Add" is clicked, that user is supposed to be displayed on a list.

This is how I tried it.

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TimeIsMoney.Models;

namespace TimeIsMoney.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();
        public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddUser(UserModel user) 
        {
            users.Add(user);
            return View(users);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model TimeIsMoney.Models.LoginModel
@{

}
@functions{
    public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}



<div id="main-content" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <h1>Time is money my friend!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <h2>1000kr</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <button class="btn" onclick="start()">Start</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <form >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Hourly wage" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="AddUser()" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <ul>
                <li>Dave</li>
                <li>Pete</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Wage:</label>
            <ul>
                <li>500kr/h</li>
                <li>500kr/h</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <br />
    <br />






</div>
```

Model:

```
namespace TimeIsMoney.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Wage")]
        public string Wage { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Am I on the right path? 
How can I move on from here?

UPDATE:

```
public ActionResult AddUser(UserModel user) 
    {
        var list = Session["myUsers"] as List<UserModel>;
        list.Add(user);
        return View(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly on the right path excluding way you're trying to store your users list.

Since ASP.NET MVC controller instance is created for every request and disposed after view is rendered and passed to the browser - it will be new controller holding new `List<UserModel>` created on every request.

So you have to store it somewhere else (session variables, file on server's disk, database and so on). Usually database is best choice for this.

In the case you want to store it in session variable, you should add something like this into `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["myUsers"] = new List<UserModel>();
}
```

and then in your controller's methods you will be able to access this list as

```
var list = Session["myUsers"] as List<UserModel>;
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to use a session in that case.
The session should be placed in the controller, right?

Comment: Thank you Andy! Aren't I supposed to store the users instead of the list?

Comment: Hmm...not quite sure what do you mean by "store the users instead of the list"....Store each user separately in separate session variable? Doesn't seems to be good idea.

Comment: Alright. But in that case, shouldn't I return the list instead of the users? Like this:
`public ActionResult AddUser(UserModel user) 
        {
            var list = Session["myUsers"] as List<UserModel>;
list.Add(user);
            return View(list);
        }`

Comment: Surely you have to use this list obtained from session variable everywhere instead of your `users` variable defined in controller. In fact, you don't need that `users` at all.

Comment: Thank you Andy! One last thing: How do I call the controller method from the button onClick()?

Comment: You have to add "method" attribute - as usual. In your case it shoud look like `<form action="/Home/AddUser">`. Of course, it's better to use `Html.BeginForm` helper method. The same story with your form inputs - use approptiate helpers instead of creating markup by yourself. It looks like you're not quite familiar with ASP.NET MVC views, so I really suggest you to have a look here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs Notice it is about first  version of MVC, but it might help to to understand the concept.